# Link Ancora não funcionando HTML

Tags: html, css, link

Boa tarde, estou fazendo um site projeto e nele tem aqueles links ancoras que levam de uma parte a outra da página, mas não está funcionando certo.

Coloquei o link como

```
  <a href="#violao">
    <div class="col s6 m3 valing-wrapper" id="">
      <div id="violao" class="valign-wrapper">
        <span id="cursosspan">Violão</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

E para chamar o link coloquei:

```
<a name="violao"></a>
```

Mas não está funcionando corretamente e não entendo o pq, alguém pode me ajudar?

Servidor teste: http://cliente.creativecode.art.br/TriadeGospel/cursos-triade-gospel.php

Alguém poderia me indicar também um script para ele ir até o link rolando a pagina mais suavemente?

Comment: pelo que vi no seu dominio vc está usando url amigaveis.. ja tentou chamar assim no href ? http://cliente.creativecode.art.br/TriadeGospel/cursos-triade-gospel.php#violao , fiz isso no seu site e funcionou.. era esse o problema?

Comment: Seria interessante você separar as perguntas em questões diferentes, senão a resposta fica muito ampla

Comment: Pedro, a âncora está funcionando, nesse exemplo do violão, aconselho você a colocar a ancora para a imagem diretamente, desse jeito `#imagemesquerda`

Comment: Pedro, adicionei na resposta um exemplo básico de fazer scroll suave usando jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não está funcionando porque você está usando o mesmo nome `violao` na âncora e no `id` da `<div id="violao" class="valign-wrapper">`.

Ao clicar no link, o HTML irá buscar antes a `id` da `div` que tem o mesmo nome da âncora.

O que deve ser feito é colocar um nome diferente para a âncora ou para a `div`.

**Exemplo:**

```html
<a href="#violao2">
    <div class="col s6 m3 valing-wrapper" id="">
      <div id="violao" class="valign-wrapper">
        <span id="cursosspan">Violão</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a name="violao2"></a>
Violão
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

### Edit

Pode usar scroll "suave" usando `animate` do jQuery, mas é preciso que a âncora seja uma `div` com `id`, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript: $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#violao2').offset().top }, 600);">
    <div class="col s6 m3 valing-wrapper" id="">
      <div id="violao" class="valign-wrapper">
        <span id="cursosspan">Violão</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="violao2"></div>
Violão
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Não deu certo o efeito para chegar até o link

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Estranho né ? Fiquei perdido agora

Comment: Aqui não apareceu nada

Comment: O que acontece ao clicar no link, nada? Nem se move?

Comment: Não dvd, nem se move

Comment: No link do site na pergunta tem como ver isso?

Comment: Os outros links que fiz, de acordo com o que foi passado por você acima aparecem na URL, mas esse ai JavaScript não funcionou, nem aparece nada na URL

Comment: Tem como falar contigo via wpp ou fb?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar a função *animate* do JQuery:

```
$("#Menu").click(function(){    
   $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#elemento").offset().top
     }, 800);
});
```

Você precisa saber a posição do elemento na qual o scroll será direcionado.

```
$("#elemento").offset().top
```

Dar uma olhada nesse conteúdo: [Scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/s61x7c4e/).